# R binary / decimal conversion confusion - AIS data

Tags: r, binary, ais

I'm working with AIS (automatic Identification System) data for positioning vessels. I was able to follow [this guide](http://www.it-digin.com/blog/?p=20) to decode almost all the bit of information successfully (when compared to online decoding done [here](http://www.maritec.co.za/tools/aisvdmvdodecoding/)).

However, I'm running into a problem with the Longitude part. I *think* it has to do with the decimal value being negative, but I can't figure out what to change in my code to get it right.

**TLDR version**: how do I get from the binary string 1101001000001001001110010000 to a decimal value of -48196720 (or 48196720)?

**Full version**:

toy data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# choose an example - two strings are provided.  
# The first string shows the issue with the longitude, 
# whereas the second string (where longitude is positive) has no issue
s <- "15E3tB001;J@BLPaK5j7qFA406;d" 
# s <- "133m@ogP00PD;88MD5MTDww@2D7k"
### for input into the online decoder - use these: 
# !AIVDM,1,1,,A,14eG;o@034o8sd<L9i:a;WF>062D,0*7D
# !AIVDM,1,1,,A,133m@ogP00PD;88MD5MTDww@2D7k,0*46

temp <- data.frame(V6 = s) %>%
    # splitting the AIS info into separate characters
    mutate(char_split = str_split(V6,pattern=""))
temp$Text <- apply(temp, 1, function(x) paste(unlist(x$char_split), collapse = ","))        

temp <- temp %>%
    select(-char_split) %>% 
    # and then into separate columns    
    separate(Text, into = paste0("v", 1:43, sep = ""), sep = ",", fill = "right") 

ASCII <- temp %>%
    select(v1:v43)
# translating to ASCII
ASCII <- apply(ASCII, c(1, 2), function(x) utf8ToInt(x))
# translating to 6-bit
ASCII <- apply(ASCII, c(1, 2), function(x) ifelse(x <= 88, x - 48, x - 48 - 8))
```

Once the data are in ASCII, need to translate to binary

```
# making binary
Binary <- apply(ASCII, c(1, 2), function(x){ paste(rev(as.integer(intToBits(x))[1:6]), collapse = "")})
# pasting all the binary info into a single string
temp$Binary <- apply(Binary, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "" ))
temp <- temp %>%
    select(V6, Binary) %>%
    # selecting bits of the single binary string, 
    #and translating back to decimal, as per the guide
    mutate(MMSI = strtoi(substr(Binary, 9, 38), base = 2),
            SOG = strtoi(substr(Binary, 50, 60), base = 2)/10,
            Accuracy = strtoi(substr(Binary, 61, 61), base = 2),
            Lon = strtoi(substr(Binary, 62, 89), base = 2)/600000,
            Lat = strtoi(substr(Binary, 90, 116), base = 2)/600000,
            COG = strtoi(substr(Binary, 117, 128), base = 2)/10,
            Heading = strtoi(substr(Binary, 129, 137), base = 2))
```

output:

```
select(temp, -Binary, -V6)
```

when I compare to the online decoder, everything matches, other than the longitude. In the decoder, the result is 80.3278667 (even though it's really -80.3278667), whereas mine is 367.0646. Trying to reverse-engineer this, I look at the relevant substring of `temp$Binary`:

```
mine <- substr(temp$Binary, 62, 89)
RevEng <- -80.3278667 * 600000
binaryLogic:::as.binary(as.integer(RevEng), signed = FALSE) 
mine
```

So it looks like the RevEng value matches the right-end tail of my binary string, but I can't figure out why it doesn't match the full binary string, or what to do from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what the blog post is telling you, longitude is a **signed** integer. However, it uses only 28 bits while R uses 32 bits internally. You therefore have to handle the [two's compliment conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) your self. For any number with the highest bit set, you have to subtract `2^28`, e.g.:

```
mine <- "1101001000001001001110010000"
strtoi(mine, base = 2) - 2^28
#> [1] -48196720
```

You can identify those numbers either with `substr` on the binary string or by looking for numbers `>= 2^27`.

BTW, the same applies to latitude with the modification that it uses only 27 bits.

Comment: @user2602640 for `latitutude >= 2^26` you have to subtract `2^27`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation... for posterity - the code + solution work well, BUT - 1) only for AIS message types 1 and 3 (for example, type 18 had different placements of information within the binary string). and 2) there seems to be an issue with decoding the SOG field - the online decoder occasionally shows values that differ from the output here...